# How to protect Oauth2 implicit flow from iframe

Tags: security, iframe, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm using Oauth2 `implicit flow` to secure Single Page Application & Rest API.

If you are unfamiliar with oauth2 implicit flow, quick overview:

We are using hidden iframes & little javascript to get access tokens & "refresh"(actually getting new token, as long as users are logged in the authorization server) it when expires.

Now it looks very easy for malicious site to contain the same iframe and just retrieve the access token from the hash fragment if the user is logged in.

I've looked at `X-Frame-Options` they can't prevent redirects and only can prevent from rendering the content inside. But our token is on the url fragment which already arrived to the browser.

As this was our "own" app we skipped the approval step by the user, granted access token automatically as long as the redirect_uri matches & user logged in. Probably this one is also sacrificing our security one step more.

This looks like an unacceptable security hole, is there any suggestions?

Comment: _“Now it looks very easy for malicious site to contain the same iframe and just retrieve the access token from the hash fragment”_ – that should be prevented by the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: But the hash fragment(which is the most secret part of this case) of the request is arrived & it can be retrieved by the parent window no? Or does SSL protect this?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.. after viewing your source and extracting the parameters you send, a malicious user could do this:

```
        var uri = addQueryString(authorizeUri, {
            'client_id': '11',
            'redirect_uri': returnUri,
            'state': nonce,
            'scope': 'bio notes',
            'response_type': 'token',
        });

        console.log(uri);
        $('body').append(`<iframe src="${uri}"/>`);

        $('iframe').css({
            'display' : 'none'
        })

        $('iframe')[0].addEventListener("load", function () {
            var uriWithToken = $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.location.href;

            token = uriWithToken.split('access_token')[1].split("=")[1];
            expires = uriWithToken.split('expires_in')[1].split("=")[1];

            console.log(uriWithToken);
            console.log("TOKEN = " + token);
            console.log("EXPIRES = " + expires);
            $('iframe').remove();
        });
```

Thank you very much for your token ill be on my way...

Comment: a malicious user could steal their own token... oh no...
unless you find an XSS vulnerability I don't understand your point (XSS required due to SOP)